# How to Page Results of "php -info" in PHP CLI on Windows

Tags: php

I am trying to find where php is loading its ini file when I use it from the command line on Windows Vista. But when I run

```
php -info
```

Although it gives my the phpinfo() output, there is so much output that even scrolling up I can only see the last third or so.

Is there a way of paging the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could try php -info | more, unsure if it still works in Vista, though.

Answer (score 1):

Grep/search through the `php -info` output like this:

`C:\> php -info | find /i php.ini`

Of course, the CLI may not be using a file called `php.ini`, but it's likely to be called *`something.ini`*, so you might grep a little looser:

`C:\> php -info | find /i .ini`

(OTOH: if you're using cygwin, you'd use grep: `php -info | grep .ini`)

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the output to a file and look at it at your leisure...

```
php -info > myinfo.txt
```

Comment: This is great and probably more useful - although I'm afraid I gave the accepted answer ot SiViG because it answered the exact question I asked. Thanks though.